# Create an automatic history (version control) of my emacs org-mode files

Tags: emacs, version-control, org-mode, auto-versioning

I love Emacs org-mode but I sometimes wish I could tell when I wrote a specific line or made a specific change.

It would be great to have an automatic versioning mechanism that would keep track of all the changes (or deltas), say every hours and timestamp all the changes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to just let version control be version control: keep your files in git or some other existing VCS. Then you just need a way to automate the commit process either after every change or periodically - for example, see the discussion in https://superuser.com/questions/132218/emacs-git-auto-commit-every-5-minutes

Answer (score 3):

My solution is as follows (inspired by Bernt Hansen's setup: http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#HourlyCommits):

I'm under Windows 10, and I have a git repository for all my org files.  Emacs is set up to save all open buffers at 00:59 every hour, and on top of every hour, a scheduled job runs a batch script executing a git commit.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer! Thanks.